# PHP forms which retain value on submit

Tags: php

Ok so I got a form and usability is important to me. If the user completes the form and then hits submit but there are errors on the form I have set values to echo back

e.g. 
`<input class="input_phone" name="phone" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST['phone']; ?>" maxlength="15" />`

The value entered will be back in the form field so that the user doesn't have to retype every field.

How do i achieve the same effect with radio buttons?

`<input class="radio" name="q1" type="radio" value="YES">`

If i set the value to `$_POST['q1']` How do I set it to `YES`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is same with input text, just with attribute `checked`.

```
<input class="radio" name="q1" type="radio" value="YES" <?php echo $_POST['q1'] === 'YES' ? 'checked' : ''; ?>>
```

Comment: Works perfect.. Why the three "===" ?

Comment: === is compare type and value

Comment: '==' means they have the same value, '===' means they have the same value and type. For instance '0 == false' is true, but '0 === false' is false - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: I know what it is I just don't get why `===` is used over `==` I think they would function the same..

Answer (score 1):

```
if isset($_POST['q1']){
   echo '<input class="radio" name="q1" type="radio" checked="checked" value="YES">';
}else{
   echo '<input class="radio" name="q1" type="radio" value="NO">';
}
```

Comment: ty Trinh, however I found xdazz's solution much cleaner.

Comment: OK, you will have variable not set if user did not check the previous form. should be isset first and then check the value

Comment: I will test for that and report back thank you for bringing that to my attention

Comment: Actually it works as it should. If it isn't checked the form doesn't submit and displays a required field warning. For another radio which isn't required it sets as NULL - conclusion is that xdazz's code is working correctly. Maybe I am misunderstanding you're comment, but I don't see any fault in this code.